# how to increase expression limit from default value(100) in inellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

In Intellij Idea while evaluvating particular expression,  i came to know the evaluvate window does showing only 100 records of that expression. Even though if the expression having more than 100 records it holds the limit of 100 only.  But for my project purpose i have to view and compare more than 100 records. Can anyone help me to find how to get more than 100 records for a single expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on any list and choose `Adjust Range`. This will allow you to view as many items as you wish, or if there is a hard limit somewhere, to adjust the range so that you can move through your whole list.